# "RelationRecord object of apyori module" apriori algorithm python

Tags: python, data-science, apriori

Excuse me for my english,
I'm trying to recognize properties that come up frequently in a set of data to deduce a categorization using the apyori package of python. i'm practicing on a dataframe of 20772 transactions and the largest transaction is 543 items.

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2c94.png)

I converted this DataFrame into a list :

```
liste = df.astype(str).values.tolist()
```

I got this list

[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldKAh.png)

I used the apriori function of the library apyori to generate the association rules:

```
from apyori import apriori
rules = apriori(liste, min_support= 0.01, min_confidence= 0.2)
```

to display the result I converted the rules variable to a list :

```
MB = list(rules)
```

The problem is that instead of showing me the rules but it shows the RelationRecord "RelationRecord object of apyori module".

like here

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmb33.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get list of rules from RelationRecord, convert RelationRecord to list

```
listRules = [list(MB[i][0]) for i in range(0,len(MB))]
```

[listRules preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRFxk.png)