# Association Rule mining using a student dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, apriori, orange

I have a dataset like this:

```
Id|Sem|Grade|Rating|SUB
1|2|A|3|sub1
1|4|C|1|sub2
2|2|B|2|sub1
```

I want to form association rules for the above data and recommend sub1,sub2 to students. How do I do it?
I tried:

```
records=[]
for i in range(0,60):
    records.append([str(df.values[i,j]) for j in range(0,5)])
from apyori import apriori
assosciation_rules=apriori(records,min_support=0.1)
assosciation_results=list(assosciation_rules)
```

The output is not understandable.Is there any better way.The output is like this:

```
[RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'0'}), support=0.3333333333333333, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'0'}), confidence=0.3333333333333333, lift=1.0)]),....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
for i in range(0,60):
    records.append([df.columns[j]+'='+str(df.values[i,j]) for j in range(0,5)])
```

This will a) increase readability and b) get rid of the error that your code treats all zeros the same (no matter which column they are from)

Answer (score 0):

One better way to read the results would be to put the contents of the record into a list. The method to do so is provided in the answer to this question: [“RelationRecord object of apyori module” apriori algorithm python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344368/relationrecord-object-of-apyori-module-apriori-algorithm-python)

Comment: That is just one part of my problem.Could you look into the other too?